# How to make Xcode automatically conform to a protocol

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, interface, code-generation

When I use a prototype table view, I always have to conform to the protocol `TableViewDataSource`. I always forget what methods I need to implement, so I have to look at the source of the protocol every time. This is really time consuming.

I think Xcode must have a feature that automatically implements the needed methods for you, right? Just like IntelliJ IDEA, Eclipse, and Visual Studio.

I want to know where can I find this feature. If there's isn't, is there a workaround for this? At least I don't have to open the source code of the protocol each time I conform to it.

If you don't understand what I mean, here's some code:

I have a protocol

```
protocol Hello {
    func doStuff ()
}
```

When I conform to it,

```
class MyClass: Hello {

}
```

I often don't remember the names of the methods that I need to implement. If Xcode has a feature that turns the above code, into this:

```
class MyClass: Hello {
    func doStuff () {
        code
    }
}
```

Now you understand what I mean? I just want to ask where to find such a feature.

Comment: See similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27331588/autoimplement-swift-protocol-methods-in-xcode

Comment: The linked answer is the only approach.  After you have created a couple of tableview controllers the methods will be in your memory :)

Comment: As far as I understand this question, it is not the same as the above link from @AlessandroChiarotto. This question here is about implementing the needed functions when I conform to a protocol. Hope somebody knows an answer soon.

Comment: Xcode is great for one thing: the interface builder, that one is amazing. Regarding code and dev features it is on the level of a simply text editor, don't even start comparing it to IntelliJ :/

Comment: I have implemented a [Xcode plug-in](https://github.com/xlc/XLCXcodeAssist) to provide suggestion for missing methods for both Swift and ObjC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well if i understood your problem then here is a workaround:

try to define methods with protocol as prefix like here `hello` then you'll not have to remember the methods just start typing protocol name and XCODE will prompt you with all available methods see here:

[image]

And if you want autocomplete protocol try
[Snippets](https://github.com/burczyk/XcodeSwiftSnippets)

Comment: Bad naming practices are hardly a valid solution for what is a shortcoming of the IDE.

Comment: Its according to iOS naming practices as you can see in AppDelegate application functions naming or tableView dataSource naming. You can also refer raywanderlich [swift guidelines](https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide#delegates)

Comment: I found this quite nasty as this is hindering my common programming workaround. I rather prefer to the built-in functionality of adding missing protocol requirements through Refactoring.

Answer (score 16):

**Xcode 9** : you can add missing Protocol Requirements by add new shortcut to your Key Bindings Set

1. From the top Xcode menu (top left) choose Preferences.
2. Choose Key Binding.
3. Search about protocol. you will find Command called `Refactor -> Add Missing Protocol Requirements`
4. Press on Key column then add your shortcut. `ex: cmd + shift + M`

**Now** you can add missing Protocol Requirements by clicking on class name name (or his extension) then press your shortcut

[image]

Comment: i added key like your example. i am pressing the same but it not showing me my protocol method. what i did wrong here please tell me thanks ...

Comment: This only does it for missing protocol methods and not optional child inheritance right? The menu is blank for me in that case

Answer (score 6):

Xcode 9, takes care of implementation of mandatory methods of Swift Datasource & Delegates.

Look at these snapshots, with example of `UICollectionViewDataSource`:

Indicating warning to implement protocol methods:

[image]

By clicking on 'Fix' button, it has added all mandatory methods:

[image]

Comment: Does this require a specific setting being turned on?  I am still not getting the option to auto generate methods with Xcode 9.2

Comment: @slackwars - Can you please share, what (which protocol) have your tried. This warning/error will be visible, if there is any mandatory function to be compulsory implemented. If all functions/methods are optional (or if already you have added/implemented in your code) , then this warning won't be indicated/shown.

Comment: class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

Comment: Link to gist image: [link]https://gist.github.com/linuxjet/bed2add074ef32fe38639e9c5809fe2e

Answer (score 3):

Very similar to Amjad's post, Xcode 9/10 brings the functionality to add missing protocol requirements right from within the code editor.

Just "right click" on the class name: "Refactor" --> "Add Missing Protocol Requirements"
[image]

Answer (score -3):

Xcode won't do it for you.

If you look at the documentation for the protocol, it's clearly marked which functions you have to implement:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/