# Always error "does not conform to protocol 'ViewModifier'"

Tags: swiftui

I have a very simple ViewModifier but no matter what this error always happen
-> Type 'MySSSAJHKDKJLHSADKJASDKJDS' does not conform to protocol 'ViewModifier'

```
struct MySSSAJHKDKJLHSADKJASDKJDS: ViewModifier {
 func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    return  content.foregroundColor(.cyan)
        .font(.subheadline)
 }
 }
```

Comment: Just curious, why did you name your struct like that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [see why "type does not conform to protocol" in Xcode (swift)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36872667/see-why-type-does-not-conform-to-protocol-in-xcode-swift)

Comment: i named it weirdly on purpose because there is another answer saying the name may be duplicated. i visited your link also it does not help with my problem. it asked me to add protocol stub but i m having protocol stub already

Comment: What are your Xcode, target, iOS version?

Comment: Compiled fine here, Xcode 13.4. Look for possible duplication of ViewModifier protocol in your project (naming conflict).

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I have a file and struct named Content. That conflicts with the body function parameter. Renaming or deleting that file works.